# Express.js & Mongoose Query Issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to query my MongoDB for a single document using `_id`. I am using Mongoose (version: 4.11.1). When I try to run the query, I pass in the `_id` as a URL param on the route `localhost:3000/poi/one/595ef9c8c4891179f8b4bbfb`.

When I hit enter, the browser will just continue loading and never complete. I am able to see the "getting one POI" in the console. But never see anything else.

I am using mLab to host my DB. And there is only 1 document inside.

**mLab Document:**
[image: mLab Screenshot]

**Here is my code for the query:**

```
let express = require('express');
let router = express.Router();

let {Poi} = require('../models/db-model');

router.get('/one/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('getting one POI');
    Poi.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).exec(function (err, poi) {
        if (err) {
            res.send('error occurred')
        }
        else {
            console.log(poi);
            res.send(poi)
        }
    });
});
```

**My database model:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// point of interest schema
let poiSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 1,
        trim: true,
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cost: {
        type: Number,
        required: false
    }
});

// instantiate models
let Poi = mongoose.model('Poi', poiSchema);

// export models
module.exports = {Poi};
```

I have been stuck with this problem for hours now and can just not figure out what the issue is.

**EDIT:**

Mongoose Configuration:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('../app-config.json');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// connect to mLab Collection
mongoose.connect(config.dbUri);

module.exports = {mongoose};
```

Comment: Turn on mongoose debugging and see if the query actually issues and with what values are actually sent to it. Use `mongoose.set('debug',true)` before your server startup and about the same place as `mongoose.connect()`. On that subject, have you possibly changed your `mongoose.connect()` recently due to the deprecation warning message? Because a lot of people are getting this change wrong, and the result is that not request actually gets issued as an unresolved callback is pending.

Answer (score 0):

In their official documentation for `findOne`, Mongoose recommends using `Model.findById()` method when querying by the `_id` field. You may read the documentation specifically for `findById` here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById

Essentially it would look something like:

```
Poi.findById(req.params.id).exec(function (err, poi) {
  // ...
```

Comment: I gave that a shot. But it still proceeds to never complete the request, the browser just keeps loading.

Comment: @kstullich Could you post what your configuration is for mongoose? This is likely in your main/index file and will look like `mongoose.connect(...)`. By default, mongoose buffers model function calls internally and will hang until a successful connection is made (apparently this occurs without raising an error).  You can also disable this by disabling buffer commands on the schema (to debug if this is the bottleneck), `mongoose.Schema({...}, { bufferCommands: false })`.

Comment: please take a look at the edit I made to my post about my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is very simple.

while `req.params.id` is a `String`, it doesn't equal to the ID that mongo generates. and in order to query by id, you have to convert the `String` to an `ObjectId`, and this can be done in several ways.

If you require `mongoose` in your module, you can just convert the string to object id, by doing: `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)` and then you have your id as an Object rather than a string, and you can query with success.

Comment: Just gave that a shot and it did not work. The query still never executes and the browser never finishes loading.

Comment: You required 'mongoose' in your file?

Comment: Yeah I required it

Comment: Try to console inside the callback function.

Comment: It never gets to the callback, that is the issue. So putting a console log, it will never show

Comment: What happens if you do console.log(Poi.findOne) before the findOne method?